# Unable to clone a shared repository via ssh (mercurial)

Tags: ssh, mercurial, bitbucket

I am having an issue with mercurial.  I have ssh keys set up between my machine and the bitbucket account I am cloning with and I am able to clone any repo that I have created.  However I am trying to clone a friends repo and she has given me read access, however when I try to clone via ssh I get the following error:

"remote: conq: repository access denied.
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!"

I am able to clone this repo via https and I am totally lost.  It seems like an ssh issue but I am lost.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the [ssh troubleshooting BitBucket tips](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Troubleshoot+SSH+Issues) works, make sure you are not using `sudo` when trying to clone (as in "[SSH to bitbucket returing Permission Denied (publickey)](https://serverfault.com/a/483919/783)")

The key is to make sure your `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub)` ssh files are used by the git clone command, and that your public key is in your account (which it should, since you can clone your own repos with ssh).